# What happens to gadgets of players that leave a match

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

I'd never leave comp nor do I actually play it, I'm asking about a casual game!

Say I'm a kapkan but for whatever reason I need to leave the game after the round has started. I've placed all 5 of my traps, what will happen to those once I've left the match, do they stay up and potentially help my team or do they also disappear with me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They stay up. I don't even think grenades you threw that haven't exploded disappear when you leave.

Comment: Grenades are (as of this moment) persistent, I've been in a match where someone Teamkilled everyone and left before the grenade went off.